# What is "Base Path" when composing a new API on BlueMix's API manager?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I am trying to create a new API in Bluemix with the API Manager service. One of the initial things that it wants to know is the "base path" of the API.  I decided that must be the public URL of the API (e.g., "http://cpe-personalityexplorer.mybluemix.net/") that is common to all of my API calls, but apparently that is not the case.  API Manager doesn't seem to like anything I put there, and I can't find any helpful documentation that explains what it is looking for or why it doesn't like what I entered.  I don't get any error messages, just a red box around that input field and a disabled submit button.

Can someone tell me exactly what I should enter in that field?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, it seems that this field is asking for the root of the API URL, sans protocol, server, and domain.  I left the field blank and the API Manager replaced it with "/".
It would be nice if API Manager would give an error message in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have opened a documentation defect to get this issue addressed.